# Codeigniter - Sweetalert didnt work in controller

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, controller, sweetalert

I tryied to make a sweetalert when the user fails the authentication in the login but it never appears when the page reload, isn't just the sweetalert, the messages with HTML code too. Check my controller code

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('login_model','', TRUE);
        }

    public function index()
    {       

                if(isset($_POST['password']))
                {
                        $this->load->model('login_model');
                        if($this->login_model->login($_POST['username'],($_POST['password'])))
                        {
                        $this->session->set_userdata('username', $_POST['username']);
                        redirect('home');
                        }else
                        {
                                redirect('login', 'refresh');
                                $var = '<div class="alert alert-success"> <i class="ti-user"></i> This is an example top alert. You can edit what u wish.
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">×</span> </button>
                                </div>';
                                echo $var;
                        }
                }
                $this->load->view('templates/header');
                $this->load->view('login/index');
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }

        public function logout()
        {
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            redirect('login');
        }

}
```

I tried too with `swal("Hello")` with this SWAL class:

```
$('#sa-basic').each(function(){
    swal("¡Error!", "Datos de autenticación erróneos, vuelva a intentarlo", "error");
});
```

Comment: If you're redirecting the page, are you sure the sweet alert is being shown? Usually one needs to involve some sort of session to keep the alert from showing on a page after a redirect. Additionally. when you execute `$('#sa-basic').each()`, does sa-basic exist at the time? Are you sure you're running it after it's been rendered to the DOM (Using `$(document.ready)` or running it right before `</body>`?)

Comment: the sweetalert does not show itself, in fact, the sweetalert is only shown if I remove the redirect ('login', 'refresh') but that causes me not to load then the icon. Any way to solve it?

Comment: You need to look into flash messages Alex. They're stored in session, and persisted through a redirect, and then output.

Comment: You're awesome, thanks! working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Alexander you need to flash data to fire swal(). Here is my code to do that

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('error')): ?>
<script>
swal({
  title: "Error",
  text: "Your request can not be completed",
  icon: "<?php echo site_url('Your Icon Destination'); ?>",
  button: false,
  timer: 5000,
});
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Same code you can make for success this time it will be

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('success')): ?>
<script>
swal({
  title: "Congratulation",
  text: "Your request has been completed Successfully!",
  icon: "<?php echo site_url('assets/slim/lib/sweetalert/icon/cancel.svg'); ?>",
  button: false,
  timer: 5000,
});
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

from controller you can make flash data like

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('success','Action Completed');
```

or

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('error','Action Not Completed');
```

Please vote if this help you